# Substance Painter Problem: Texture Badly Unwraps in Some Places

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv

I guess I can ask about substance painter here as well. 
I don't know how to prevent from happening thing that is presented on the picture. When I put materials or smart materials on my mesh, it looks good in some places, but in other (usually the tall parts of mesh) it looks like this. I've tried to use different options in substance such as UV Scale, Projection, Filtering, UV rotation, UV Offset to different layers of materials, it didn't help so far. How? 
P.S. Baking is done.

[image]
The same texture, but looks good on one side and bad on the other.

Comment: So far this is a question more about Substance. Show UV map for you object, in particular how do islands on UV map for the bad looking faces differ from good looking ones. It seems from the screenshot that either faces are scaled down too much or they are rotated in a wrong way

Comment: Yes, I guess the reason is that automatic UV unwrapping made those faces very small on UV map.  I looked into UVs and these faces are really small for their size.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about Blender.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem with your UV Layout.

1. Go in your Blender Project
2. Select the Model and tab into Edit Mode with all faces selected.
3. Go in the UV Image Editor, enable the checkmark "Stretch" and select "Area" underneath.

[image]

I used a Cube as an Example.
Edit your UV Layout until all Faces have a dark blue color.

Hope that helps.

[image]